# How to get The Loop working with $wpdb->get_results()

Tags: loop, get-posts

I am doing a rather complicated custom query on a blog's front page, and trying to show the results using The Loop as shown here: [Displaying posts using a custom SELECT query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query)

The query filters posts by a custom field that contains a date (show only posts where that field is set to today or later), and orders them by that date.

The query returns the correct posts, but if I turn them over to The Loop, the results are shown as if I were doing a regular query, not the specialized one (i.e. the wrong posts show up).

The people in [this forum thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/setup_postdata-problem) have the same problem; I utilized the $GLOBALS workaround shown there, but to no avail.

```
  global $post;
  global $wpdb;

 $querystr = "SELECT wposts.* FROM $wpdb->posts wposts ...... some conditions and joins";
 $eventsPosts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

 print_r($eventsPosts); // shows CORRECT data      

 if ($wpdb->num_rows > 0)
  foreach ($eventsPosts as $post) 
   {

    /* workaround */
    $stored_post = clone $GLOBALS['post']; // Why, Wordpress, why?
    $GLOBALS['post'] = $post;              // Why are you making me do such terrible things?

    setup_postdata($post);
    the_post();
    the_title(); // shows INCORRECT post

    /* workaround: Restore global */
    $GLOBALS['post'] = clone $stored_post;

   }
```

however, this output gives me the result as if I had done a  regular query, not my special one. Ie, `the_title()` outputs the title of a post that isn't in the query result.

If I test output the custom query result:

```
print_r($eventsPosts);
```

I get the *correct* posts. Only when I use Loop functions, the wrong results are output.

Is there a canonical, correct way of doing this that works?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out I didn't follow the instructions in the manual to the letter: I seem to have declared `global $post` too early. I don't entirely see through this but it works fine now using this code:

```
$eventsPosts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

if ($eventsPosts)
 {
   global $post;
   foreach ($eventsPosts as $post) 
    { 
     setup_postdata($post);
     the_title(); // or whatever - the loop functions work
    }  
 }
```